# Mobile devices that are Nvidia Tegra profiler 2.0 compliant

Tags: android, nvidia, profiler, tegra

I am profiling a JNI Android Application . So far I managed to profile it with [Android-NDK-profiler](http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/). It is very simple so I want to go further and get info of the hardware too, like cache misses, bus speed etc.

I have read that the NVidia Tegra profiler is very powerfull but there is not much info about the devices that support it. I know that it needs Tegra 4, and that for example this device supports it: http://shield.nvidia.com/.

The problem is thta it has no camara integrated so it is not valid for me.

Has anybody tried any device like a mobile or tablet that is compatible with Nvidia Tegra profiler??

Comment: you can get a tegra note tablet: http://www.nvidia.com/object/evga-tegra-note-tablet.html

Comment: That seems profileable for sure, as it is mentioned in Tegra profiler page, but I read that the camera and other features are no so good. Do you know if this mobile is profileable with Nvidia Tegra profiler: http://www.asus.com/Tablets_Mobile/ASUS_Transformer_Pad_TF701T/specifications/

Answer (score 1):

normally any Tegra4 and K1 based device should work, but I would recommend the Shield/Note from Nvidia for your work, not only are they quit cheap, but their android is left very much vanilla (aside from some stylus things on the note) which makes it easier to work with.

There is also the advantage (so far) of a "usable" update policy.